# Castle dependency injection Lifestyle

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I should point out that I'm relatively new to Castle, so don't really know what i'm doing with it yet.  The gist is, that I'm trying to make a custom lifecycle of an object with Castle Windsor.  I'm not entirely sure how this should be done, however, the closest approximation I can find to how it should work I have detailed below.

I want a singleton, but I can't release this type and assign a new instance to.

ie,

```
public interface IMyObject { string text; }

public class MyObject() : IMyObject    {
    public string text;
}

var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(Component.For<IMyObject>().ImplementedBy<MyObject>().LifeStyle.Singleton);

MyObject item = SomeMethodGetInstance(); //Defines scope for instance 1
item = container.Resolve<IMyObject>(item);
Print(item);     

>>instance 1
....

item = container.Resolve<IMyObject>();  //gets instance 1
Print(item); 
>>instance 1
....

item = SomeMethodGetInstance()  //New scope defined, now using instance 2
```

I want to be able to release the instance, but Windsors definition of a Singleton is too rigid for my needs.

```
container.Release(item);    //I need to release the current instance, this doesn't work.
```

or

```
container.Kernal.ReleaseComponent(item);  //Don't work either.
```

So, when I set a new item as the current it doesn't revert to instance 1.

```
item = container.Resolve<IMyObject>(item);  //sets the currect instance of MyObject
Print(item); 

>>instance 2
```

I need to store a variable that has a custom scope, neither Singleton or Transient are going to cut the mustard for me.  I need to be able define the scope, when the stored variable goes in and out of scope.

More to the point, if I have another class B, which is dependent on A, then if I get A from outside the container, how do I set A in the container?  This is fine in a singleton scenario, but I can't set it for a transient Scenario, however, with Singleton, once it's set, I can't release it, which is necessary.

How do I do this please?

I want to do this in code rather than in xml, as i'm registering the classes dynamically.

Comment: You can create custom lifestyle, based on you requirements. See example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1366597/1275399

Answer (score 0):

You can register your component as a single as follow

```
public void Register(string name, Type service, Type impl)
{
   WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
   IKernel kernel = container.Kernel;
   kernel.AddComponent(name, service, impl, LifestyleType.Singleton);
}
```

You can release the component as follows

```
kernel.ReleaseComponent(yourResolvedSingletonInstance)
```

Comment: A singleton can't be released.  I tried the Register implentation you suggested, however it doesn't work, Windsor doesn't like the name.

Answer (score 0):

> I want a singleton

The default lifestyle for Castle Windsor *is* singleton.

> but I can't release this type and assign a new instance to.

But that's not a singleton then.

> How do I do this please?

You didn't specify exactly what it is that you want to do. Do you want a new instance every time that you call `Resolve`? That's `LifeStyle.Transient`.

Comment: It's not a singleton and it's not a transient, it's a shade of grey.  I am using objects retrieved from a database.  It is clear to me, that my implementation is somewhat bad, however, it's what I need.  The closest approximation is a perWebRequest, however I'm not using http.

Comment: You didn't **specify** what it is that you need. You need to describe it **precisely**. You're clearly not speaking in clear terms because you say you want a singleton, but you don't. Your code indicates it should be something like transient but you say not.

Comment: I have a database call, this gets an object, which technically is transient, however I can't inject this into other classes because it's marked as transient, a new instance gets created each time, which defeats the database call in the first place.  I can't mark the object as a singleton, as I can't then do multiple fetches of the item, as I can't release it.

Comment: Why are you mixing dependency injection with objects that are hydrated from a database call? That right there is a big part of your confusion.

Comment: Because the class has a dependency on the database entity.  Forgive me, is this not what is meant by dependency injection?

Comment: I mean specifically, why are you mixing the use of a dependency injection container into your application to manage this? Keep the container out of your application logic.

Comment: @Craig: I think Jason is trying to say that you're using a "newable" as an "injectable." See https://plus.google.com/114807587132568234264/posts/fgLH9Qy8Db4

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a custom factory to produce your instance? It could invoke the DI framework to produce a new instance any time it needs one, but you could define your own logic to determine when it needs to release an old instance.

This approach answers your second question, too. Class `B` should not take an `A` as a dependency, but rather an `AFactory`. Because `B` may be longer-lived than `A`, it needs to ask the factory for the "current" instance of `A` each time it goes to use it.

Comment: This might be the way forward.

Comment: No, it's not! You don't need a DI container to get data out of a database and then pass it along to a consumer of that data. You're just needlessly complicating things and buying yourself nothing. I suspect StriplingWarrior's answer was made before he knew the context under which you are intending to use it.

Comment: It's all a lot of frustration for me, is all I know.

Comment: @Craig: Jason's right. It sounds like rather than injecting this object with a specific lifetime, what you really want is a cached repository. Ultimately, it would probably work in a very similar fashion to the Factory that I recommended, but since you're producing a piece of data rather than a service, "Repository" is a more appropriate name than "Factory." Rather than "releasing" an instance, you'll be purging the cached data.